# MVC Website URL Change Handling - Where Do I Put It?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have removed the word 'XYZ' in my application URL and want to handle that any old URL having 'XYZ' will be redirected to a new URL after removing 'XYZ' on the same domain.

Here 'XYZ' is not a controller name, it is extra path set up in IIS.

I want to handle URL changes in the MVC application hosted in Azure (PaaS).

**Example**

- Old URL: `https://ServerName/XYZ/{Controller Name}/{Action}`
- New URL: `https://ServerName/{Controller Name}/{Action}`

I was looking to set up some kind of rule setup in web.config

```
<rule name="Enforce canonical hostname" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^/zcw$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://Server/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Here this rule itself will filter the '\XYZ' from the URL.
I am not sure if it is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Code worked for me after adding in web.config.

```
    <rule name="Root Request with slash XYZ to Controller/Action" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^XYZ" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/Controller/Action" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I display my previous URLs with a new URL for a page.

```
public class UrlPath : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication app)
        {
            app.BeginRequest+=new EventHandler(_BeginRequest);
            app.EndRequest+=new EventHandler(_EndRequest);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

         void _BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

             HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication) sender;
             app.Context.Items["start"] = DateTime.Now;

             if (app.Context.Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains("tours_list.aspx"))
             {
                 app.Context.RewritePath(app.Context.Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Replace("tours_list.aspx","tours_cat.aspx"));
             }

         }
         void _EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
             string log = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(app.Context.Items["start"].ToString())).ToString();
             Debugger.Log(0,"duration","request took " + log+Environment.NewLine);

         }
    }
```

```
<system.webServer>

    <modules>
      <add name="UrlRewrite" type="UrlRewrite"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks Mehran for prompt response. Sorry for the confusion with my question earlier. I have updated the question now for batter understanding. Here 'XYZ' is not a controller name, its a extra path setup in IIS

Comment: Hi Saurabh, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Has the previous URL of your page changed?
I have already made changes to this script using httpmodule.

Comment: Thanks Mahran for example, but can we set up some kind of rule in web.config as mentioned in my question?

Comment: According to your latest edition, I have no idea. Sorry